# What is the significance of the if statement in this code?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am currently learning JavaScript through some tutorials and this example came out in the tutorial.
I'm just confused why must the if statement be there.
I tried erasing the if statement and it still worked. Can someone help me please.

```
var timesVisited=0;
var dateVisited = 'Never';

if(localStorage.myLastVisit){
    var visit = JSON.parse(localStorage.myLastVisit);
    timesVisited = visit.numVisits;
    dateVisited = visit.dateVisits;
}

$("#dateVisit").html(dateVisited);

timesVisited++;
$("#numVisit").html(timesVisited);


var myVisits = {};
myVisits.numVisits = timesVisited;
var d = new Date();
var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();
myVisits.dateVisits = hours + ':' + minutes;
localStorage.myLastVisit = JSON.stringify(myVisits)
```

Comment: It still *works* but in a different way than before. It's now not loading the data from localstorage and not restoring the `timeVisited` and `dateVisited`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried erasing the if statement and it still worked.

Only if `myLastVisit` is already in `localStorage`. If it isn't there (which is what the `if` is testing for), without the `if` you'll get an error from `JSON.parse` because you'll pass `undefined` into it, which will get converted to a string with the characters`undefined` in it because `JSON.parse` requires a string, which will then fail because that's not valid JSON. The `if` is there so that if the setting isn't present, the default values assigned to `timesVisited` and `dateVisited` are used.

Works if the setting is there:

```js
var timesVisited=0;
var dateVisited = 'Never';

var visit = JSON.parse(`{"numVisits": 2, "dateVisits": "2020-03-27"}`);
timesVisited = visit.numVisits;
dateVisited = visit.dateVisits;
console.log(timesVisited); // 2
console.log(dateVisited);  // "2020-03-27"
```

Fails if it isn't:

```js
var timesVisited=0;
var dateVisited = 'Never';

var visit = JSON.parse(undefined); // ERROR
timesVisited = visit.numVisits;
dateVisited = visit.dateVisits;
console.log(timesVisited);
console.log(dateVisited);
```